# How to copy the clipboard content/data with shortcut from keyboard cmd + c/ctrl + c in main or renderer process in electron

Tags: electron

I register a global shortcut when user copy something but couldn't get the data from the clipboard object in both renderer or main

**main.js**

```
globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+C', () => {
          var clipboardText = clipboard.readText();
          console.log(clipboardText);
          mainWindow.webContents.send( 'copied', clipboardText);
})
```

If we listen this event in renderer.js file even then I'm not able to get the clipboard data.

**EVENT IS GETTING FIRED I HAVE LOGGED OUT**

**renderer.js**

```
ipcRenderer.on('copied', (e, args) => {
    console.log('data received -> ' + args);
    var clipboardText = clipboard.readText();
    console.log('clipboard data'+ clipboardText);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy solution. Instead of listening from main process, we can listen to clipboard data changes from the renderer process directly using **electron-clipboard-extended** npm package.

```
const clipboard = require('electron-clipboard-extended');
clipboard.on('text-changed',() => {

    var clipboardText = clipboard.readText();
    //we get the data in clipboardText but only when text changes

}).startWatching();
```

Documtentation for [electron-clipboard-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-clipboard-extended)